# SQL Server query and OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join

Given the table Stuff

```
IdStuff  StuffName  IdLanguage
-------  ---------  ----------
1        Stuff 1    1
1        Stuff 2    2
```

and the view: vwLanguages

```
IdLanguage   Name
----------   ----
1            Language 1
2            Language 2
3            Language 3
```

I would like to obtain:

```
IdStuff   StuffName  IdLanguage
-------   ---------  ----------
1         Stuff 1    1
1         Stuff 2    2
1         NULL       3
```

I've tried with RIGHT JOIN, but I did't succeed...

```
SELECT
    S.IdStuff, S.StuffName, vwLanguages.IdLanguage
FROM
    Stuff S
    RIGHT JOIN vwLanguages ON vwLanguages.IdLanguage = S.IdLanguage
```

The problem is that only 2 rows are shown, for language 1 and language 2...

Comment: Show us your attempt, at least. Also, how do we "know" that we should generate an `IdStuff` value of `1` for the final row?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Even a CROSS JOIN wouldn't do what you're after, although it would be marginally closer.

Comment: you will never obtain what you want because idstuff will be null for language 3

Comment: Why does the second row have a string of "stuff 1" instead of "stuff 2"? If you're going to make up bogus tables and data, at least have them make some bit of sense.

Comment: Can you please explain why the third row should have `IdStuff=1`? Where on earth does that `1` come from?

Comment: Don't dumb things down for us. You're going to get much better answers if you explain your *actual scenario* instead of making up stuff and have it not end up making any sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RIGHT JOIN` is almost never the correct approach. I think what you're looking for is a `CROSS JOIN` between distinct `stuff` IDs and `language` rows, and then a `LEFT JOIN` to the `stuff` details if available.:

```
SELECT
    subStuff.IdStuff,
    s.StuffName,
    l.IdLanguage
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT IdStuff
    FROM Stuff
) subStuff 
CROSS JOIN vwLanguages l
LEFT JOIN Stuff s
    ON s.IdStuff = subStuff.IdStuff
    AND s.IdLanguage = l.IdLanguage
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc285/2)

The reason that you need the `CROSS JOIN` is that you're basically wanting each distinct ID from `stuff` to be matched up with each record from `language`, even if there's no matching `IdLanguage`.  Once you have this Cartesian product of these two sets, you then want to get the `StuffName` if it happens to have a corresponding `stuff` ID and `language` ID.

The implementation is a little hard to explain because the requirements are a little weird, and don't really match up with your table structure.

For example, why is `IdStuff` not unique in the `stuff` table?

I'm assuming this is a contrived example, but it raises a lot of other questions.

Comment: thanks for the query! I would appreciate if you explain why RIGHT JOIN is not a solution?

Comment: @user3104183 You could probably get the correct results with `RIGHT JOIN`, but you could instead re-order your joins and use `LEFT` instead for style reasons... most people would agree that it just flows or reads better than `RIGHT`.

Comment: The problem is the same, even with LEFT or RIGHT outer join...

Comment: @user3104183 Yea, the `CROSS JOIN` is needed in both cases.

Comment: Why? I'm a just a beginner, please explain, as for me it looks a simple OUTER JOIN condition...

Comment: @user3104183 Since you want a row even when there is no match at all (the third row), you need to cross join because there is no left- or right-relationship with any rows in the table with language 3, because no such rows exist. You could also do it, I suppose, with a union, but then I don't know how you'd IdStuff = 1 in the first column.

Comment: @user3104183 I added an explanation to the answer... but Aaron's explanation is better, so reference that one instead.

Comment: @user3104183 *YOU asked for that empty row*. If you want to "get it" you'll need to explain it to us, not the other way around.